# SUM() returns wrong values when using left join with GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables called shops, services and rating.

Shops have

[image: Shops have]

Services have more than one services for the shops
[image]

Rating has the rating of the shops
[image]

I need to get the shop details with services and also rating in single query.

I have done this query

```
select shops.*, count(distinct rating.id) as rating_count, 
sum(rating.rating) as total_rating,
GROUP_CONCAT(distinct services.servicename SEPARATOR " <=> ") as servicename
from shops
LEFT JOIN rating on rating.shop_id = shops.id
LEFT JOIN services on services.shop_id = shops.id
group by shops.id
```

It returns
[image]

But shop1 has total_rating 21. But it shows 42.

I need correct total rating and also all services for that shops.

Check this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ece82/4)

Comment: Why are your service names called `shop1`, `shop2`, etc.?  This is making your question very confusing.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Fixed now.

Comment: Perhaps it can be more elegantly written as follows http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ece82/29

Comment: Or if you must use GROUP_CONCAT (yuk): http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/21077/4

Answer (score 0):

```
select q1.id, q1.shopname, q1.rating_count, q1.total_rating,
GROUP_CONCAT(distinct services.servicename SEPARATOR " <=> ") as servicenamefrom
FROM
(select shops.*, count(distinct rating.id) as rating_count, 
sum(rating.rating) as total_rating
from shops
LEFT JOIN rating on rating.shop_id = shops.id
group by shops.id) q1
LEFT JOIN services on services.shop_id = q1.id
GROUP BY q1.id,  q1.shopname, q1.rating_count, q1.total_rating
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ece82/20

To understand your problem run the select w/o group by and just examine the rows you get after joins but before aggregation.  You will release where double counting is coming from.

Comment: Without group by returns single row with total_rating 46 and all three services

Comment: your query works fine I think. But little complicated for me. I need to do this query in codeigniter

Comment: This is what I mean by no group by: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ece82/24  I don't understand what you mean by the query being complicated.  Do you want it to be simple or do you want it to calculate what you need?  You could split it into 2 simple queries with a single left outer join in each of them.

Comment: I mean little complicated to do this query in codeigniter. Thanks. I ll try to do this CI